# Parse number that is seperated with arrow

Tags: javascript

I am having the following input data `["$245.00 ➝ $200.48   ", "➝", null, "", "$245.00 ➝ $200.48    ", "$247.00 ", "$210.00 ➝ €160.00   ", "€210.00 -> $160.00  ", "£210.00 -> £160.00  ", ]`

I would like to split the data by arrow and get the numbers via an array back.

I tried the following:

```js
const data = ["$245.00 ➝ $200.48 ", "➝", null, "", "$245.00 ➝ $200.48 ", "$247.00 ", "$210.00 ➝ €160.00 ", "€210.00 -> $160.00 ", "£210.00 -> £160.00 ", ]

let getDigits = (numb) => {
  let digits = +numb.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');

  return digits
}

let hasNumber = (s) => {
  return /\d/.test(s);
}

let splitArrow = (s) => {
  if (s === undefined || s === null || s === "" || !hasNumber(s)) {
    return []
  } else {
    let arr = s.split(' -> ').join(',').split(' ➝ ').join(',').split(',')
    return [getDigits(arr[0]), getDigits(arr[1])]
  }
}


for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(splitArrow(data[i])[0])
  console.log(splitArrow(data[i])[1])
  console.log("#################################");
}

// wanted output:
/* 245.00
200.48
""
""
""
""
""
""
245.00
200.48 */
```

As you can see I am currently getting an error. (see above)

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why `247, 210 and 160` is not in wanted output ?

Comment: Also, `->` is not the same as `➝`. Is that deliberate, or a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a single regular expression to match `([\d.]+) ➝ .*?([\d.]+)` (digits, followed by `➝`, eventually followed by more digits). If the regular expression fails, return nothing, else return the two capture groups (containing the numeric characters matched):

```js
const data = ["$245.00 ➝ $200.48 ", "➝", null, "", "$245.00 ➝ $200.48 ", "$247.00 ", "$210.00 ➝ €160.00 ", "€210.00 -> $160.00 ", "£210.00 -> £160.00 ", ]

const output = data.map((item) => {
  if (!item || typeof item !== 'string') {
    return [];
  }
  const match = item.match(/([\d.]+) (?:➝|->) \D*([\d.]+)/);
  if (!match) {
    return [];
  }
  return [match[1], match[2]];
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Isn't that what you want? You only want the two number parts to be included in the final array?

Comment: Yes, but besides this arrow `➝` I am also facing this `->` arrow

Comment: Just alternate with `->` in a non-capturing group

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to combine `Array#map` and `Array#filter` to transform the input data to the required output format as described below:

```js
const data = ["$245.00 ➝ $200.48 ", "➝", null, "", "$245.00 ➝ $200.48 ", "$247.00 ", "$210.00 ➝ €160.00 ", "€210.00 -> $160.00 ", "£210.00 -> £160.00 ", ]

const result = data
  .map(item => {

    /* Transform strings to number pairs if possible, or return empty
    array */
    if (typeof item === "string") {

      /* Remove whitespaces and currency symbols from string and 
      split result by array schemes */
      const parts = item.replace(/[\s$€£]*/g, '', '').split(/➝|->/)
      
      if(parts.length > 1) {
      
        /* Filter valid string parts and parse to floating point 
        numbers */
        return parts.filter(part => !!part).map(Number.parseFloat)
      }      
    }
    
    return [];
  })

console.log(result);
```